# Convert Java to Python using cx_Oracle SQL/XML query

Tags: python, oracle, cx-oracle

I have an existing solution in Java to extract data from an Oracle database. I do it like so:

```
String tmp = "begin ? := pkgioexportora.request(?); end;";
String xml = "<ttc.export.public.data.search><query><popid>1</popid> <moduleid>3</moduleid><only_changes>0</only_changes></query></ttc.export.public.data.search>";
CallableStatement callableStmt = oracle.prepareCall(tmp); 
// Register the type of the out param - an Oracle specific type
callableStmt.registerOutParameter(1, OracleTypes.NUMBER);
callableStmt.setString(2, xml);
```

This construct returns a job id which I'm later required to use in the WHERE clause of a SELECT query.

I've tried using just a cursor and input the complete statement, without the CallableStatement stuff, but no luck.

```
cursor = con.cursor()
cursor.execute("begin 2 := pkgioexportora.request(xml_stuff_here); end;";)
```

callproc seems to give me similar error.

I've tried searching for solutions, or similar things done, but yet to come up with any examples. Is it possible to do such a thing with cx_Oracle or am I stuck with my Java code for doing this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [cursor.callfunc()](http://cx-oracle.readthedocs.io/en/latest/cursor.html#Cursor.callfunc) in cx_Oracle. As in the following:

`result = cursor.callfunc("pkgioexportora.request", cx_Oracle.NUMBER, [xml_stuff])`

You could also do it this way, but its more complex:

`var = cursor.var(cx_Oracle.NUMBER)
cursor.execute("begin :1 := pkgioexportora.request(:2); end;", [var, xml_stuff])
result = var.getvalue()`

Comment: After much fiddling I arrived at a similator solution. This looks cleaner.